# Angular2 Services and good practices

Tags: angular, service

I'm fairly new to the `angular2` world and am looking for the best way of doing some things.

One of those is : What would be the best initial value for a Service querying an Http endpoint?

Consider the following code :

```ts
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core'
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable'
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject'

@Injectable()
export class CounterService {
    private _counter : BehaviorSubject<Number> = new BehaviorSubject(0)
    public counter : Observable<Number> = this._counter.asObservable()

    constructor () {
        this._counter.next(0)
    }

    public addOne () {
        this._counter.next(this._counter.getValue() + 1)
    }
}
```

I could use this as follows:

```ts
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>Counter value is {{sCounter.counter | async}}</h2>
      <button (click)="increment()">add one</button>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App {
  constructor(private sCounter : CounterService) {
  }

  increment () {
   this.sCounter.addOne() 
  }
}
```

(c.f. this [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/upxMUek9TcqYCZAq6oFm?p=preview))

But obviously some services will query an API to get data and that's where I'm not sure exactly how to handle this.

`BehaviorSubject` requires an initial value (and that's great) that will be given to its subscribers but since the service doesn't query anything until you ask it to, its initial value won't be what's expected and might break the UI.

Example:

```ts
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core'
    import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable'
    import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject'

    @Injectable()
    export class UserService {
        private _user : BehaviorSubject<User> = new BehaviorSubject({} as User)
        public user : Observable<User> = this._user.asObservable()

        constructor (http: Http) {}

        public fetchUser(id) {
            this.http.get(`/user/${id}`).subscribe((user) => { this._user.next(user) })
        }
    }
```

As you can see, when I subscribe for the first time to this service I will receive `{}` (cast as User) instead of a real user, and that could lead to problems.

Is there any good pattern to follow about this?

Answer (score 0):

I just added a `.filter` to get only the values I want and it does the trick just fine. :)

```ts
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core'
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable'
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject'

@Injectable()
export class UserService {
    private _user : BehaviorSubject<User> = new BehaviorSubject({} as User)
    public user : Observable<User> = this._user.asObservable()
                                     .filter(user => user instanceof User)

    constructor (http: Http) {}

    public fetchUser(id) {
        this.http.get(`/user/${id}`).subscribe((user) => { this._user.next(user) })
    }
}
```